# Need some help for clarifying an example on infinite-dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

In the book *Linear Algebra Done Right*, example 2.14 said that $P_m(\mathbb{F})$ is a finite-dimensional vector space for each non-negative integer $m$.

$P_m(\mathbb{F})$ is defined as "For $m$ a nonnegative integer, $P_m(\mathbb{F})$ denotes the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$ and degree at most $m$"

Then in example 2.16, it showed that $P(\mathbb{F})$ is infinite-dimensional.

Consider any list of elements of $P(\mathbb{F})$. Let $m$ denote the highest degree of the polynomials inn the list. Then every polynomial in the span of this list has degree at most $m$. Thus $z^{m+1}$ is not in the span of our list. Hence no list spans $P(\mathbb{F})$. Thus $P(\mathbb{F})$ is infinite dimensional.

I am a bit confused on why $P_m(\mathbb{F})$ is finite dimensional, and $P(\mathbb{F})$ is infinite dimensional.

Is it because $P_m(\mathbb{F})$ is just talking about polynomials with degree at most $m$, while $P(\mathbb{F})$ is talking about polynomials with degree that can be higher than $m$?

Comment: Yes that's the reason. In $P(\mathbb{F})$ the degree is unbounded. You have polynomials of all degrees.

Comment: I love when people answer their own question in the question itself :)